# SQL: Join 3 columns

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:

1. Profiles:

| id | created_at | full_name | invited_by | invite_count | is_admin | avatar_url | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9e4d5874-1482-41e2-a481-d29ce38b5b67 | 2022-11-25 15:53:51.642357+00 | Admin user |  |  | true |  | admin@email.com |
| 0f0cf390-5952-4fd6-a436-1d384a2c61b7 | 2022-11-25 15:53:51.642357+00 | Test user |  | 2 | false |  | test@email.com |

2. Questions:

| id | created_at | question | owner_id | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d792c1b6-5578-4771-9192-08aeee3894c3 | 2022-11-25 17:11:54.031778+00 | 53w5 | 9e4d5874-1482-41e2-a481-d29ce38b5b67 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |
| 3892d4ed-7ab0-4006-b983-ad7eaf0094d5 | 2022-11-25 17:17:45.133241+00 | test | 9e4d5874-1482-41e2-a481-d29ce38b5b67 | 2d76bc68-3f1b-4801-8d8d-65c3986ee7c0 |
| ab3a0783-1fbe-4d8d-ac56-ce2bd01ff04a | 2022-11-25 18:03:56.078212+00 | test | 0f0cf390-5952-4fd6-a436-1d384a2c61b7 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |
| 0c2a25ad-53d7-499a-8a6d-9b2ed5fde967 | 2022-11-25 18:11:50.776553+00 | www | 0f0cf390-5952-4fd6-a436-1d384a2c61b7 | 2d76bc68-3f1b-4801-8d8d-65c3986ee7c0 |

3. Votes

| user_id | question_id | created_at | answer | option_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0f0cf390-5952-4fd6-a436-1d384a2c61b7 | 3892d4ed-7ab0-4006-b983-ad7eaf0094d5 | 2022-11-25 18:01:24.149577+00 |  | 1 |
| 0f0cf390-5952-4fd6-a436-1d384a2c61b7 | d792c1b6-5578-4771-9192-08aeee3894c3 | 2022-11-25 18:01:29.606896+00 |  | 2 |

I want to construct the following table:

| id | created_at | full_name | avatar_url | questions_published | votes_cast |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I tried this:

```
 SELECT profiles.id,
    profiles.created_at,
    profiles.full_name,
    profiles.avatar_url,
    count(questions.owner_id) AS questions_published,
    count(votes.user_id) AS votes_cast
  FROM public.profiles
  LEFT JOIN public.questions
  ON profiles.id = questions.owner_id
  LEFT JOIN votes
  ON profiles.id = votes.user_id
  GROUP BY profiles.id;
```

The result looks like this:

| id | created_at | full_name | avatar_url | questions_published | votes_cast |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0f0cf390-5952-4fd6-a436-1d384a2c61b7 | 2022-11-25 15:53:51.642357+00 | Test user |  | 4 | 4 |
| 9e4d5874-1482-41e2-a481-d29ce38b5b67 | 2022-11-25 15:53:51.642357+00 | Admin user |  | 2 | 0 |

but should looks like this:

| id | created_at | full_name | avatar_url | questions_published | votes_cast |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0f0cf390-5952-4fd6-a436-1d384a2c61b7 | 2022-11-25 15:53:51.642357+00 | Test user |  | 2 | 0 |
| 9e4d5874-1482-41e2-a481-d29ce38b5b67 | 2022-11-25 15:53:51.642357+00 | Admin user |  | 2 | 2 |

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: and which database are you using, i wioshed you all would add a dbfiddle, which makes the solution much easier

Comment: Dead right, no one wants to create a fiddle with so much data before even start on writing down a solution, but no one wants to provide a solution without testing it. So, such questions are on risk to don't get answered just because of a missing fiddle.

Comment: Join Questions and votes basis question id. Instead of this `LEFT JOIN votes ON profiles.id = votes.user_id`, try this `LEFT JOIN votes
  ON questions.id = votes.question_id`

Comment: count(distinct questions.id) as questions_published, count(distinct votes.question_id) as votes_cast

Comment: Don't follow JHH's advice. While counting distinct entities would solve this, don't muddle through with such tricks. You are cross joining unrelated questions and votes, thus creating an intermediate result that you don't want and that can become huge on big tables. Instead, properly join what needs be joined (question counts and vote counts) from the start. Please see my answer on this.

Comment: I agree with @ThorstenKettner, it’s a dirty fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are cross joining a users questions and votes. If a user asked two questions and cast two votes, you create four result rows of all combinations (2 x 2 = 4). If you count then, you will find four rows with questions and four rows with votes.

Instead, aggregate before joining, i.e. join the user's question count and vote count to their profile.

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.created_at,
  p.full_name,
  p.avatar_url,
  COASLESCE(q.cnt, 0) AS questions_published,
  COASLESCE(v.cnt, 0) AS votes_cast
FROM public.profiles p
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT owner_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM public.questions
  GROUP BY owner_id
) q ON q.owner_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM votes
  GROUP BY user_id
) v ON v.user_id = p.id
ORDER BY p.id;
```

Comment: I'm facing this error: `column "q.cnt" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`.

Comment: Oops, the `GROUP BY` must be removed from the main query of course. Sorry. I've updated my answer.